# Scala macro to generate new instance of class with dependency injection of trait with abstract fields

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

**Update: Modified the code to use macro annotation, but still missing something**

The following code works (question below):

```
object MyTypes {

  trait RealType

  class Container[RT <: RealType] {
    this: RT =>
  }

  trait SomeRealType extends RealType

  trait PartialRealType extends RealType {
    val needed: Int
  }
}

import MyTypes._

object Container {
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  def helper[RT <: RealType : c.WeakTypeTag](c : Context) : c.Expr[RT] = {
    import c.universe._
    val weakRT = weakTypeOf[RT]
    val genTree = q"new Container[$weakRT] with $weakRT {}"
    c.Expr(genTree)
  }
  def apply[RT <: RealType] : Container[RT] with RT = macro helper[RT]
}

val ok = new Container[SomeRealType] with SomeRealType
val ok_quasi = Container[SomeRealType]
```

---

I wish to be able run the following:

```
val partial = Container[PartialRealType]{val needed: Int = 0}
```

I've tried to do this:

```
object Container {
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  def helper[RT <: RealType : c.WeakTypeTag](c : Context)(body: c.Expr[Unit]) : c.Expr[RT] = {
    import c.universe._
    val weakRT = weakTypeOf[RT]
    val genTree = q"new Container[$weakRT] with $weakRT { $body }"
    c.Expr(genTree)
  }
  def apply[RT <: RealType](body: Unit) : Container[RT] with RT = macro helper[RT]
}
```

However this doesn't work.